# E-commerce in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Good afternoon, I am making a website on e-commerce. And it allows me to add products and everything.

But when I want to see my product list in admin panel and main page, I get two errors.

1. Error number one:

> Trying to get property 'status' of non-object (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Aplicaciones Web Para I4.0\Tecnologia
> Express\resources\views\frontEnd\index.blade.php)

**Code where the error is marked**

```
<?php if($product->category->status==1): ?>
```

2. Error number two:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Aplicaciones Web Para I4.0\Tecnologia
> Express\resources\views\backEnd\products\index.blade.php)

**Code where the error is marked**

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo e($product->p_name); ?></td>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo e($product->category->name); ?></td>
```

**I also attach the screenshots**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq9ST.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwhj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin,

Both of those errors mean that properties that you are trying to access can't be accessed because the object on which you are trying to access them is `null` or non-existent. So, for the first screenshot in `blade` file you probably don't have `$product` variable available, or on `$product` (if it is available) `category` is not defined.

In the second screenshot `$product->category` is not available again, which probably means that on `$product` you don't have `category` available.

Make sure you are providing `category` together with `$product` from the controller.

You can do something like `$products->with('category')`. Also, to debug if you have or don't have `category` on the product try doing `{{ dd($product) }}` in your `blade` file and see what is available on `$product`.